# IDA PRO change .rdata value

Tags: disassembly, ida

How can I change the circled value? (5CB4F8B3h)

[image]

I am not a professional, but it is vital for me to influence this value.
Treat it with understanding :)

Comment: I can't figure out exactly HOW to change this value.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hex editor, locate the sector containing the hex value you need to modify, and change it. TimeDateStamp is in epoch time, so you should get the timestamp in [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and convert it to hexadecimal (you may use a calculator in "programming mode", type the decimal timestamp and you will get its hex value.

After some googling, I found that a tool called PE Explorer can modify the timestamp of PE executables, which is the thing you're attempting to do, so this could be a better solution for a no professional. [The instructions are here.](http://www.heaventools.com/time-date-stamp-adjuster.htm) I'm in no way affiliated to this product, I just thought it may be useful for your needs.

Comment: The problem is that in the hex editor I can't find this sequence (5CB4F8B3)

Comment: @FrozenSpace, the byte order is reversed in the file, try searching B3F8B45C

Answer (score 0):

Modify these values in IDA with idc function `PatchDword`:

```
success PatchDword(long ea,long value);
```

This function changes a dword (4 bytes) at address `ea` to `value`.
You want to change 3 values at `0x14010D484`, `0x14010D4A0` and `0x14010D4BC`.
In IDA run `"File->IDC command..."` and enter this script with `newValue1`, `newValue2` and `newValue3` set to new values for these addresses:

```
if( !PatchDword(0x14010D484, newValue1) || !PatchDword(0x14010D4A0, newValue2) || !PatchDword(0x14010D4BC, newValue3))
  Message("Failed to patch!\n");
```

Click OK and check the output window - there should be no error messages.
Generate DIF file - `"File->Produce File->Create DIF file..."`. The DIF file is a text file with a list of patched bytes. Each line looks like:

```
0005A827: 5D BB
```

In this example `0005A827` is an offset in the binary on the disk, `5D` is the original value, `BB` is the new value.
Apply this DIF file with some patch applyer or do it manually in a hex editor - move to the offsets from the DIF file and change the values of the bytes.

Your binary can use checksum checking. In this case it will not run after the patch. The checksum fix depends on the checksum type used.